# VHDL - why do we need to declare signals for processes?

Tags: vhdl

Just revisiting some VHDL and I was wondering inside processes for example, why do we need to declare a signal for a clock for example? Then later on in the code assign it to the port from the entity...

EXAMPLE VHDL:

```
signal clk_int: std_logic := '1';

BEGIN
clkgen: process(clk_int)
begin
clk_int <= not clk_int after 50ns
end process ckgen

ck_l <= clk_int;
```

In this example ck_l is a physcial port from the d flip flop yet we create and mess around with clk int then return the value to ck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the port `ck_l` in this case is probably declared with direction `out`, so It cannot be read from. If you want to read it, like you would need to if you want to have a process that is sensitive to it, you need to use a signal or declare the port as `inout` or `buffer`.

Comment: You probably don't want to use `inout` unless it's truly a bidirectional port (i.e. on an FPGA pin, with a tri-state buffer). Use of `buffer` is somewhat controversial as well. Note that VHDL-2008 allows reading from `out` ports with no extra coding workarounds.

Comment: Yes, I should have probably added that while the inout and buffer solutions are possible, they are not preferable.